# Does IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource> preserve the order of elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Assume two lists, A and B so that A = (1,2,3) and B = (4,5,6). Will A.Concat(B) preserve the order so that the result is (1,2,3,4,5,6)?

Comment: Why the H*LL downvote this? Upvoting to counter unless someone can provide a good reason. If you need clarrification then ask for it in the comments...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserving order with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.  IEnumerable.Concat will simply turn two list into a single list by attaching one to the end of the other.  Order within each list will be preserved.

Comment: Is it explicitly mentioned somewhere in documentation? I mean whether it is a subject to change as an implementation detail, or is it clearly stated that this behaviour won't change in future.

Comment: @Dmitry MS can't change this behavior without breaking a huge number of applications and redefining the meaning of concatenate. IMHO, it's safe to depend on this.

Comment: Agree that this should have been mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's pretty much what concatenation means.

Obligatory MSDN quote: ([Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx))

> **Return Value**
>
> Type:
>   [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)(TSource)
>
> An [IEnumerable(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) that contains the
>   concatenated elements of the two input
>   sequences.