# OrderBy and Distinct using LINQ-to-Entities

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

Here is my LINQ query:

```
(from o in entities.MyTable
orderby o.MyColumn
select o.MyColumn).Distinct();
```

Here is the result:

```
{"a", "c", "b", "d"}
```

Here is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[MyColumn] AS [MyColumn]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[MyColumn] AS [MyColumn]
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

Is this a bug?  Where's my ordering, damnit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should sort *after* `Distinct` as it doesn't come with any guarantee about preserving the order:

```
entities.MyTable.Select(o => o.MyColumn).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o);
```

Comment: This code does not compile.  OrderBy gives the error: `The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Oh I see, it needs to be `OrderBy(o => o)` since by that point the items have already been selected (and we are working with an `IQueryable<string>`).  I've fixed your code and given you the checkmark - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question discusses the rules for Linq to Objects:
[Preserving order with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

In the database, even fewer operations preserve order.  No one anywhere preserves order when Distinct'ing (as generally a Hash algorithm is used).

Comment: Still, the query `SELECT DISTINCT ... ORDER BY ...` works as you would expect in SQL Server, and likely in other DBMS's - is there a reason the `orderby` LINQ clause is just ignored in this case when generating the SQL (it could at least throw an error)?  I still think this is a bug - the LINQ query works correctly when used on a `String[]`.

Comment: If you check the query plan, it will reveal that the ORDER BY occurs after the DISTINCT.  As such, there are strict limitations on what may appear in the ORDER BY.  This is just another case where SQL's syntax causes confusion.

Comment: What's the "query plan," and how do I view it?  I obtained that query above using SQL Server 2008 Profiler, but it obviously only gives you the final query.

Comment: put the query into a query window in SqlStudio (formerly known as Query Analyzer).  Click "display estimated execution plan".