# Linq to Entities Distinct Clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

I want to add a **distinct** to the code below. I cannot figure out the exact syntax. Thanks in advance.

```
var testdates = (from o in db.FMCSA_ME_TEST_DATA
                 orderby o.DATE   
                 select new
                 {
                    RequestDate = o.DATE
                 });
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `Distinct()` extension method.

Note that `Distinct()` may negate the existing `orderby` (I've noticed this in LINQ to SQL), so you may want to use the `OrderBy()` method afterwards.

```
var testdates = (from o in db.FMCSA_ME_TEST_DATA
                 select new
                 {
                     RequestDate = o.DATE
                 }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.RequestDate);
```

Comment: Are you sure about Distinct() negating an order by?  I'm not seeing that behavior (running a similar query), and would be very surprised if I did

Comment: @Adam - I have encountered the OrderBy/Distinct issue with LINQ to SQL, but it may not be a problem for other LINQ providers. See http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/20/use-of-distinct-and-orderby-in-linq.aspx

Comment: Wow - didn't know about that bug.  I hope that's fixed in EF4, regardless though it shouldn't affect *this* query.  +1 for posting that though.

Comment: @Adam - Yeah, it's annoying - especially because IQueryable meant in theory that you could use the same queries against various providers. In practice, you have to be aware of bugs like this (or pull your hair out).

Comment: [Linq Operations Grouped By Effect on Order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/39396)

Answer (score 3):

```
var testdates = (from o in db.FMCSA_ME_TEST_DATA
                 orderby o.DATE   
                 select new
                 {
                    RequestDate = o.DATE
                 }).Distinct();
```

The trick is to wrap your query in parenthesis so you can call the distinct method, which you already did, so all you needed was to tack on the method call at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this should work:

```
            var testdates = (
                        from o in db.FMCSA_ME_TEST_DATA
                        orderby o.DATE
                        select new { RequestDate = o.DATE }
                        ).Distinct();
```

Check this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#distinct2