# Do LINQ's Enumerable Methods Maintain Relative Order of Elements?

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

Say I have `List<Foo> foos` where the current order of elements is important. If I then apply a LINQ Enumerable method such as `GroupBy`, `Where` or `Select`, can I rely on the resulting `IEnumerable<Foo>` to iterate in the same relative order as the original list?

Comment: I won't try to answer your question directly, because @Mehrdad already did a good job of that, but if you really want to understand what Linq is doing under the covers then have a look at Jon Skeet's excellent [EduLinq series of blog posts](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, for `Enumerable` methods (LINQ to Objects, which applies to `List<T>` you mentioned), you can rely on the order of elements returned by `Select`, `Where`, or `GroupBy`. This is not the case for things that are inherently unordered like `ToDictionary` or `Distinct`.

> #### From [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) documentation:
>
> The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in `source`.

This is not necessarily true for `IQueryable` extension methods (other LINQ providers).