# Will the result of a LINQ query always be guaranteed to be in the correct order?

Tags: c#, linq

Question: Will the result of a LINQ query always be guaranteed to be in the correct order?

Example:

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 

var lowNums = 
  from n in numbers 
  where n < 5 
  select n;
```

Now, when we walk through the entries of the query result, will it be in the same order as the input data `numbers` is ordered?

```
foreach (var x in lowNums) 
  { 
    Console.WriteLine(x); 
  }
```

If someone can provide a note on the ordering in the documentation, this would be perfect.

Comment: Use `var lowNums = numbers.Where(x => x < 5).OrderBy(x => x);`

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146724/do-linqs-enumerable-methods-maintain-relative-order-of-elements. If it's an IEnumerable, it will mantain the original order.

Answer (score 6):

- For [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx): Yep.
- For [Parallel LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384150.aspx): Nope.
- For [LINQ to Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) (EF, L2S, etc): Nope.

Comment: Do you find any documentation that guarantees that the order keeps the same for Linq-To-Objects?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm pretty sure the docs say the opposite, or rather, just say nothing at all.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: I'm fairly sure that the docs say nothing even if i'm sure that it doesn't change the order in `Select` or other linq methods.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The docs don't say anything about this, but when Microsoft changes this behavior, they will break an awful lot of clients, and Microsoft isn't fond of breaking clients. They will never change the `Enumerable.Where` to produce results that are in an other order.

Comment: Interesting though is that [the documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) do state that `group by` preserves its order.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeah I had just corrected my comment to point out that it is just not mentioned. I agree that Microsoft will probably never change it. However, I would still write my code assuming order is not guaranteed. Especially since LINQ to Objects is the only one that works like that. I'd rather not base my software on a convenient coincidence.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: But if the input sequence was already ordered it would be redundant and inefficient to order it again. So it's important to know that the order doesn't change. Linq-To-Objects is incomparable with other providers that use a rdbms.

Comment: @Steven True that. They won't even *fix* `OrderByDescending`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was actually thinking of 3rd party providers and ones that don't yet exist but assuming there is no performance loss (which I think would generally be the case) I would just do my LINQ queries before I do my sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of elements retrieved by a `LINQ` is preserved, at least for `LINQ to Object`, for `LINQ to SQL or Entity`, it may depend on the order of the records in the table. For `LINQ to Object`, I'll try explaining why it preserves the order.

In fact when the `LINQ` query is executed, the `IEnumerable` source will call to `GetEnumerator()` to start looping with a `while loop` and get the next element using `MoveNext()`. This is how a `foreach` works on the `IEnumerable` source. We all know that a **`foreach` will preserve the order of the elements** in a list/collection. Digging more deeply into the `MoveNext()`, I think it just has some `Position` to save the current `Index` and `MoveNext()` just increase the `Position` and `yield` the corresponding element (at the new position). That's why it should preserve the order, **all the code changing the original order is redundant or by explicitly calling to `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`**.

If you think this

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 
foreach(var i in numbers)
  if(i < 5) Console.Write(i + "  ");
```

prints out `4  1  3  2  0` you should think this

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 
IEnumerator ie = numbers.GetEnumerator();
while(ie.MoveNext()){
  if((int)ie.Current < 5) Console.Write(ie.Current + "  ");
}
```

also prints out `4  1  3  2  0`. Hence this `LINQ` query

```
var lowNums = from n in numbers 
              where n < 5 
              select n;
foreach (var i in lowNums) { 
   Console.Write(i + "  "); 
}
```

should also print out `4  1  3  2  0`.

**Conclusion:** The order of elements in `LINQ` depends on how `MoveNext()` of an `IEnumerator` obtained from an `IEnumerable` is implemented. However, it's for sure that **the order of elements in `LINQ` result will be the same order a `foreach` loop works on the elements**.