# DISTINCT() and ORDERBY issue

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am learning about LINQ-to-SQL and everything was going well until something strange happened:

I tried to make an example of `distinct`, so, using the Northwind dabatase I wrote the following query:

```
var query = 
    from o in db.Orders
    orderby o.CustomerID
    select new
    {
        o.CustomerID
    };
```

If I print the SQL generated by LINQ-to-SQL for the query stored in `query` it looks like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[CustomerID]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[CustomerID]
```

So, as usual, the query brings all the `CustomerID` for each `Order` in the `Orders` table ordered alphabetically.

But! If I use the `Distinct()` method like this:

```
var query = (
    from o in db.Orders
    orderby o.CustomerID
    select new
    {
        o.CustomerID
    }).Distinct();
```

The query brings the expected results of the `Distinct` clause, but the `CustomerID`s are not ordered despite I wrote `orderby o.CustomerID`!

The SQL query for this second LINQ query is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[CustomerID]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t0]
```

As we can see **the `ORDER BY` clause is missing. Why is that?

Why does the `ORDER BY` clause disappears when I use the `Distinct()` method?

Comment: As an aside lambda syntax is much simpler for queries like this: `var query = db.Orders.Select(o=>o.CustomerId).Distinct();`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the [Queryable.Distinct documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456);

> The expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the unique items in source.

In other words, any order the existing IQueryable has is lost when you use `Distinct()` on it.

What you want is probably something more like this, an OrderBy() *after* the Distinct() is done;

```
var query = (from o in db.Orders
             select new
             {
                 o.CustomerID
             }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerID);
```

Answer (score 19):

Try rearranging the members to place the OrderBy after the Distinct. You'll have to revert to method chaining:

```
db.Orders.Select(o=>o.CustomerId).Distinct().OrderBy(id=>id);
```

This would be the more efficient way to set up the query in Enumerable Linq anyway, because the OrderBy would then operate only on the unique items and not on all of them. Also, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx), Enumerable.Distinct does not guarantee the return order of the elements anyway, so ordering before deduping is pointless.

Comment: ... Yes it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx. The question is, why does Distinct not maintain the order of the input elements, when it so easily could by just yield-returning?

Comment: @KeithS Did you read your link... "The result sequence is unordered."  It's not a bug when it's built into the design.

Comment: @JTorres I edited the answer based on exactly that statement in the link. In my previous comment I was agreeing with asawyer that it was indeed by design. The question remains; why did they design it that way when it could have so easily been implemented in an order-stable way?

Comment: @KeithS This might provide some insight http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx

Comment: @asawyer - So apparently Jon Skeet agrees with me; the "natural" implementation, and thus the naive expectation, is that Distinct would stream elements in the same order as they are input, removing subsequent dupes (the first duplicate is returned, others are suppressed); however he also notes this is in fact not the case with the built-in implementation.

Comment: Sounds about right. I wonder if @JonSkeet might pop in and give an opinion on this.

Comment: John Skeet's blog has moved, so asawyer's link should be http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct/

Answer (score 4):

Due to the use of distinct, the order of the returned list is not guaranteed.  LinqToSql is smart enough to recognize this, therefor it ignores it.

If you place the order by AFTER your Distinct, everything will happen as you desire.

```
var query = (from o in db.Orders
             select new
             {
                 o.CustomerID
             }).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.CustomerID);
```

or

```
var query = db.Orders.Select(o => o.CustomerID).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.CustomerID);
```

Please see this article for clarification:

[http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/20/use-of-distinct-and-orderby-in-linq.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20130318205025/http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/20/use-of-distinct-and-orderby-in-linq.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate ORDERBY and DISTINCT with this counstruction:

```
var distinctItems = employees.GroupBy(x => x.EmpID).OrderBy(x => x).Select(y => y.First());
```