# Why ".Distinct() " doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DISTINCT() and ORDERBY issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428985/distinct-and-orderby-issue)

```
listOrders.DataSource = (from sp in dbdata.Specifications.Where(i => i.Approve == "Yes" && i.Awailable_BOM == "Yes")
                                     join ord in dbdata.Orders on sp.O_id equals ord.O_id
                                     join prd in dbdata.Products.Where(k => k.Hours_prd == null) on ord.O_id equals prd.O_ID
                                     orderby ord.Special, sp.Due_date
                                     select ord.O_id).Distinct();
```

I am tring to order by "ord.Special, sp.Due_date" but it doesn't work after I put "Distinct();". So how do I order by "ord.Special, sp.Due_date" and get distinct values.

Comment: What did you expect? What happened instead?

Comment: WAHT distinct values? The way syu specify Distinct is that ALL items have to match that are returned.

Comment: Would be great to read [LINQ Farm: Using Distinct and Avoiding Lambdas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will return ordered ids:

```
listOrders.DataSource = 
   from sp in dbdata.Specifications.Where(i => i.Approve == "Yes" && i.Awailable_BOM == "Yes")
   join ord in dbdata.Orders on sp.O_id equals ord.O_id
   join prd in dbdata.Products.Where(k => k.Hours_prd == null) on ord.O_id equals prd.O_ID
   select new { ord.Special, sp.Due_date, ord.O_id } into x
   group x by x.O_id into g
   select new { g.Key, X = g.OrderBy(i => i.Special).ThenBy(i => i.Due_date).First()) } into y
   orderby y.X.Special, y.X.Due_date
   select y.Key;
```

Comments:

- select only fields you are interested in into `x`
- group those fields by field you want to be distinct into group `g`
- from each group select key (`ord.O_id`) and group item `X`, which will define order of id in result (in this case `First` occurrence of id will be returned)
- order results by `X`
- select `Key` (`ord.O_id`)

Comment: @user1508417 what is not clear to you?