# Entity Framework ignoring OrderByDescending

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

In my SQL Server database I have the following hierarchy

Inventory > Datasets > Resources > Renditions > Conformities

where each is a one to many relationship. I wanted to get the id of the three datasets with the most recently updated conformity. Conformity doesn't have its own date but takes the modified date of the parent rendition. I therefore created the following query:

```
var datasets = _inventoryRepository
    .GetConformitiesIncludeAncestors()
    .OrderByDescending(conformity => conformity.Rendition.Modified)
    .Select(conformity => conformity.Rendition.Resource.DatasetID)
    .Distinct()
    .Take(3);
```

GetConformitiesIncludeAncestors is simply returning the conformities with includes as follows:

```
return _context.Conformities.Include(conformity => conformity.Rendition.Resource.Dataset.Inventory);
```

but the SQL statement shown when stepping through the code doesn't have an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[DatasetID] AS [DatasetID]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP (3) 
        [Extent3].[DatasetID] AS [DatasetID]
        FROM   [dbo].[Conformity] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rendition] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RenditionID] = [Extent2].[ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Resource] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ResourceID] = [Extent3].[ID]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

Why is `OrderByDescending` being ignored? Entity Framework version is 6.0.1.

EDIT: I have a workaround that does the trick, but by querying in a different way. I'm still interested in why the OrderByDescending had no effect so will leave open.

*My workaround using GroupBy*

```
var datasets = _inventoryRepository
    .GetConformitiesIncludeAncestors()
    .GroupBy(conformity => conformity.Rendition.Resource.DatasetID)
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Max(conformity => conformity.Rendition.Modified))
    .Take(3)
    .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Comment: Does it work if you move the OrderByDescending after the Distinct?

Comment: @KenTucker unfortunately not as the Select has already converted the results to IQueryable<int> by that point.

Comment: @AndyNichols, why do you need to do the `Distinct`, you want the most recently updated dataset id by rendition's modified, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DISTINCT() and ORDERBY issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428985/distinct-and-orderby-issue)

Comment: I need the distinct as otherwise it will often return the same ID three times as a dataset can (and usually does) have many renditions created at the same time.

Comment: @AndyNichols, okay then, now you already have the workaround, but the original question should have been answered by the above link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the Distinct, you should get similar result like this.

```
var datasets = inventoryRepository
    .GetConformitiesIncludeAncestors()
    .OrderByDescending(comformity => comformity.Rendition.Modified)
    .Select(comformity => comformity.Rendition.Resource.DatasetId)
    //.Distinct()
    .Take(3)

SELECT TOP (3) 
    [Extent3].[DatasetId] AS [DatasetId]
    FROM   [dbo].[Comformities] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Renditions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RenditionId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Resources] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ResourceId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    ORDER BY [Extent2].[Modified] DESC
```

But after you add the Distinct, it doesn't guarantee the ordering, check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456).

> The expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the
>   unique items in source.

Comment: Accepting this answer due to the link and quote explaining the reason. However, for anyone else reading the answer please be aware that removing Distinct before a Take will alter the results you get back.