# Why does Entity Framework ignore order by when followed with distinct?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'd like to know why the following join returns values in an unordered fashion. Does distinct imply that the order of the `IQueryable` passed is not guaranteed, therefore EF does not bother generating an order by clause in the SQL.

```
 var currentUtc = DateTime.Now;
 var data = (from a in ItemsA
     join c in Customers on a.Fk_CustomerID equals c.ID into customerSubset
     from cs in customerSubset.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where cs.Age > 18)                                    
     orderby a.ID ascending
     select new
     {
       a.ID,
       a.someProperty,
       cs.CustomerUID,
       CustomerName = cs.Name,                               
       UpdateUTC = currentUtc
     }).Distinct().Take(1000).ToList();
```

The strange thing is that removing the distinct adds the order by clause in the inner query of the generated SQL (you can use Linqpad to see the SQL generated for eg.)

Now if I replace the last line with

```
.Distinct().OrderBy(x => s.ID).Take(1000).ToList();
```

I'm getting the order by clause in the SQL, whether or not I have the `orderby a.ID ascending` in the inner query. This makes sense, but why is chaining distinct after orderby also not yield the same order?

Comment: add all column (you are selecting distinct) in order by   ---

Comment: i only want to select some columns and ensure they're distinct.

Comment: DISTINCT: "The expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the unique items in source." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456

Comment: The DISTINCT operation in SQL doesn't guarantee order. Internally it performs a sort before determining if rows are identical. Even that isn't guaranteed though because the query engine can partition the data for parallel processing

Comment: @SteveGreene - yes, i just happened to read that line on msdn myself. Although it wasn't clear whether it unorders a sequence by itself, or just preserves order of the sequence passed in. Panagiotis' answer cleared that up.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428985/distinct-and-orderby-issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DISTINCT operation in SQL doesn't guarantee order. Internally it performs a sort before determining if rows are identical.

Even that order isn't guaranteed though because the query engine can partition the data for parallel processing, then recombine the partitioned data to produce the final result.

To guarantee a specific order, the `ORDER BY` clause or the `OrderBy()` call should be the last one before `Skip()` or `Take()`

Comment: Yes, msdn also mentions it gives an unordered sequence. Thought it meant it  would preserve previous order, but it actually unorders it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I think the correct documentation for this is w.r.t. IQueryable.Distinct (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct): "The expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the unique items in source."