# Entity Framework Distinct with OrderBy

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use Entity Framework 6.2 and noticed that Distinct ignores my OrderBy clause.
I have class:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PartnerId { get; set; }

    // Other properties removed for clarity.
}
```

And want to get last 20 partners of my orders:

```
var list = db.Orders.AsNoTracking()
.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.Id)
.Select(x => x.PartnerId).Distinct().Take(20).ToList();
```

The generated SQL query ignoring my OrderBy clause:

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[PartnerId] AS [PartnerId]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP (20) 
    [Extent1].[PartnerId] AS [PartnerId]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Limit1]
```

How can I get exactly last 20 partners from orders?

Comment: *what's wrong with this query?* There is no SQL equivalent of order by before distinct / group by, so EF query translator is simply ignoring it (throwing exception telling you what's wrong would have been better, but this is how it is).

Comment: There was similar question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428985/distinct-and-orderby-issue Telling short: You must sort after selection

Comment: @AlexYena I answered you in your deleted answer, that this question is not similar, because I want to sort by different column. So, after Distinct I can sort only by 'PartnerId'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DISTINCT() and ORDERBY issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428985/distinct-and-orderby-issue)

Comment: How would you do the equivalent in SQL?

Comment: @GertArnold You don't understand the DB structure. Each order have only 1 partner. And business logic need to know last 20 partners we worked with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are sorting before using Distinct. As taken from your comments, you said you cant order by `Id` because its not available. You will have to include the `Id` in the Select query then, however that Id is unique so the distinct could include duplicate partner entries.

Your only option is to use the Id field to preserve some order (since Ids are incremental) with an aggregate function.

```
var list = db.Orders.AsNoTracking()
    .GroupBy(order => order.PartnerId)
    .Select(group => new { 
        PartnerId = x.Key,
        LastId = x.Max(order => order.Id)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastId)
    .Take(20)
    .Select(x => x.PartnerId)
    .ToList();
```

This works as Ids are usually incremental, but a **date column would usually be preferred for this query**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't you put a `Select(g => g.PartnerId)` after the `Take`?

Comment: @NetMage Is there any difference in order of `Select` and `Take`?

Comment: Nope, since everything before ToList() is still IQueryable. It's essentially the same as wrapping the a T-SQL query in sqlserver with another select. It should virtually yield no performance decrease.