# IQueryable<string> orderby is not working in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor-pages

I am trying to sort an `IQueryable<String>` and bind to a selectList.

**Issue:** my code is able to pull list of all `FirstName` from the database, but it's not sorting. It seem like `Distinct()` function is removing `OrderBy`. How can I keep both?

```
<select asp-for="FirstName" asp-items="@Model.Firstname_SELECT">
</select>

public SelectList? Firstname_SELECT { get; set; }

IQueryable<string> Query = (from m in _context.My_DbSet
                            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.FirstName)
                            orderby m.FirstName 
                            select m.FirstName).Distinct();
Firstname_SELECT = new SelectList(await Query.ToListAsync());
```

I also tried this but getting an error

> string doesn't contain ref of m.FirstName

```
IQueryable<string> Query = (from m in _context.My_DbSet
                            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.FirstName )
                            orderby m.FirstName 
                            select m.FirstName).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m.FirstName);
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the second query, but once you `select m.FirstName`, the result is just the FirstName values as collection of strings. Instead of `.OrderBy(m => m.FirstName)`, try `.OrderBy(s => s)`. You can then also lose the inner `orderby`.

Comment: This post will give you some ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428985/distinct-and-orderby-issue