# Does Enumerable.Where in LINQ-to-objects preserve order?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

```
var source = new List<string> { "A1", "A2", "B1", "B2" };
var filtered = source.Where(s => s.StartsWith("A"));

foreach (var s in filtered)
    Console.WriteLine(s);    // outputs first A1 and then A2
```

It *seems* like [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534803.aspx) keeps the original order of elements when used on an ordered IEnumerable (such as a `List<T>` or `T[]`). Is this always the case? If yes, where is this documented?

Comment: The current implementation keeps the original order (as you've observed), but as you say, that's not actually documented anywhere (that I'm aware of.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft does actually document that LINQ to Objects preserves ordering. The document
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx says

> In PLINQ, the goal is to maximize performance while maintaining
>   correctness. A query should run as fast as possible but still produce
>   the correct results. In some cases, correctness requires the order of
>   the source sequence to be preserved; however, ordering can be
>   computationally expensive. Therefore, by default, PLINQ does not
>   preserve the order of the source sequence. In this regard, PLINQ
>   resembles LINQ to SQL, but is unlike **LINQ to Objects, which does
>   preserve ordering.**

As mentioned in [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq) microsoft documents for some LINQ methods that they do not preserve order. For example the [documentation of distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) mentions that this method returns an **unordered** sequence.

Answer (score 6):

The order is preserved using the Enumerable.Where method.

There was a similar question asked on SO, and the first answer breaks down which methods preserve the order:

[Preserving order with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented. Documentation of the LINQ operators is seriously lacking in many aspects, including when and when isn't order kept, when and when isn't the operation buffered, or what are the complexity guarantees.

In this case, I don't mind depending on the implementation keeping the order, because that's what all practical implementations will do.

I recommend reading the [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/03/18/edulinq-the-e-book.aspx) series by Jon Skeet where, before implementing the functionality, he explain what you should and what you should not expected of an operator.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Where` will preserve the order of an `IEnumerable<T>`.  This is not documented, so not a guarantee, however, the implementation just iterates through the `IEnumerable<T>` sequentially - in effect, preserving order - though that order is reliant on the underlying `IEnumerable<T>`'s order.  (For example, Where on a `HashSet<T>` is not ordered, but it's because the `HashSet<T>`'s enumerable is unordered.)

It does, however, include special implementations to handle certain types (such as arrays and `List<T>`), so it's not impossible that a specific collection type, at some point in the future, might return results in a different order if this would be deemed a valuable improvement in terms of speed/perf./etc.  The documentation never specifically gives an ordering guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

The Where implementation is essentially as follows with some additional variable checking added in:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Funct<T, bool> predicate)
{
   foreach (T item in source)
       if (predicate(item))
           yield return item;
}
```

As a result, assuming yield is not being done asynchronously or in parallel, it will retain the order. If your source is .AsParallel, all bets are off in terms of the order.

Comment: As a side note, I wish `Where` used `Predicate<T>` instead of `Func<T, bool>`.  .net has a lot of cool stuff in it, but sometimes the standard library developers don't seem to realize it.

Comment: This is actually pretty far from the implementation in .NET 4 - though it would give the same results.  There are quite a few custom iterator classes used in LINQ to Object's to implement Where efficiently on different underlying types.

Comment: @recursive: Doesn't make that big a difference now. With .NET 4 those are interchangeable. It did matter back when it came out though.

Comment: @recursive, they decided to go with Func<T, bool> rather than Predicate<T> as it was more generic and re-usable.

Comment: @Reed, understood, but the code above should give a good enough picture from a generalized perspective. Also, the custom iterator classes seen in the IL are often generated by the compiler (from the yield keyword) and may not reflect the developer's thought process. Also, the Yield code spit is being modified for the next version of C# to reflect optimizations found in implementing async/await.

Comment: @Jim: Yeah - it's indicative of what you'll get, but the implementation is very different (and not compiler generated).  There are custom iterator implementations for arrays, lists, etc inside of much of LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 1):

The decompilation of the LINQ where is:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
{
    int num = -1;
    IEnumerator<TSource> getenumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    while (getenumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        TSource current = getenumerator.Current;
        num++;
        if (predicate(current, num))
        {
            yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

The decompilation of the System.Collections.Generic.List.MoveNext() has the code:

```
if (this.version == ts._version && this.index < ts._size)
{
    this.current = ts._items[this.index];
    this.index = this.index + 1;
    return true;
}
```

Using these two together you can see that the the order will be preserved.  Of course Microsoft could change it in the future, but based on .NET 4.0, List.Where will be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it must preserve order, because it is able to function on infinite `IEnumerable`s.

```
void Main() {
    foreach (var element in Count().Where (i => i%2 == 1)) {
        // do something with all odd numbers
    }
}

IEnumerable<int> Count() {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) yield return ++i;
}
```

I can't find this documented anywhere though.

Comment: Well, it could be wacky and produce them out of the order: 1,0,3,2,5,4,... and still work on infinite IEnumerables :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's going to be ordered according to the iterator. Since this isnt PLINQ, the enumerable is iterated over in order of element position of the enumerable - so if you implemented some kind of custom `IEnumerator` for your class, it would return in that ordering.

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Where` follows the ordering of elements returned by the enumerator generated by calling  `GetEnumerator` on the underlying collection - looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s.aspx) the enumerator on `List<T>` is documented to follow the indexing behaviour.

Comment: "Enumerable.Where follows the ordering of elements returned by the enumerator generated by calling GetEnumerator" <-- not documented

Answer (score 0):

Without providing explicit `OrderBy`, the `Where` method cannot guarantee the order - otherwise, it would have been documented as doing such.