# Why does orderbydescending not rearranged a list?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Am I correct in understanding that a orderbydescending doesnt actually rearrange the order of a list? and if so what would be the best method around this?

```
newList= myOldList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)
                            .ThenBy(x => x.Status)
                            .Where(x => x.Status != StatusEnum.Complete).ToList();
```

This does not seem to be actually rearranging them, what would be the most effective way?

Thank you.

Comment: Rearranging them in what way?

Comment: try order by after where clause

Comment: Can you provide a small sample that demonstrates the issue? If you want to order the old list too you have to reassign  `newList` to `myOldList`.

Comment: You should also note that sorting on an enum uses the underlying numerical values, not the labels.  If StatusEnum.Complete has an underlying value of 1 and StatusEnum.InProgress has an underlying value  of 0, then InProgress will come before Complete in the sorted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order you are calling your Linq query chain it should be

```
newList= myOldList.Where(x => x.Status != StatusEnum.Complete).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Status)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Why is it needed? The `Where` should preserve order
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259560/does-enumerable-where-in-linq-to-objects-preserve-order While it is for sure good idea to filter first, is it needed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to order them after you filtered the results, `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, not an `IOrderedEnumerable`.

But you are correct to say that using the order methods on a collection doesn't order the collection itself. It *does* return an ordered version of the collection.

Edit: As Tim Schmelter says in the comments, `Where` doesn't change the order, but if you're going to sort your data, you'd better return the appropriate interface.

Comment: But `Where` doesn't change the order. Using `Where` first is better anyway because there is less to order.

Comment: Not necessary; If you query a database; the the result is going to be IQueryable and not IEnumerable.

Comment: @AlexSuleap: But it's about a List which is Linq-To-Objects.

Comment: @AlexSuleap List would be a terrible name for an `IQueryable` ;-)

Comment: Sorting first and then extracting the result will be slower than extracting the results and than sorting. Why: To sort the list linq uses quick sort which is O(n log n) in average. To extract the results is O(n). Sorting a smaller list is faster.

Comment: It's not that complicated, complexity doesn't matter but the order of operations. As i've said, if you have to sort all and then your filter throw away most of it, you've sorted a lot for no reason. If you first filter there's less to sort. When i started with LINQ this was also confusing me. E.Lippert gave me a nice example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110013/order-of-linq-extension-methods-does-not-affect-performance