# Does the order of `Select`'ing elements vary?

Tags: c#

I'm working with an object declared as shown.

```
DataCollection<Entity> collection = GetDataCollection(...);
```

Then, I'm picking out two sets of data as below.

```
IEnumerable<String> 
  array_1 = collection.Select(
    element => element.Attributes["attribute_1"] as String),
  array_2 = collection.Select(
    element => element.Attributes["attribute_2"] as String);
```

I'm terribly curious if those two arrays are guaranteed to have the same order. I.e. if their separate orders must be the same as in the original sequence. Or, at the very least, if the order would change for any reason, will the `i`th element in the first separate list still correspond to the `i`th element in the other?

Comment: to be safe, get both attrs at once `var arr = collection.Select(element => new {
      Attr1 = element.Attributes["att1"] as String,
      Attr2 = element.Attributes["att2"] as String
     });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not guaranteed to be the same. In reality, you'll probably notice that the order is typically consistent with the original collection.

If you're worried about consistency, just add an `OrderBy` clause to get the order you need (or at least one that is consistent between the two resulting collections).

Comment: Is it possible to `OrderBy` them without specifying an explicit ordering function? By that I mean an ordering function like `OrderType.WhateverYouHadBefore` or `OrderType.JustAsLongAsYouAreConsistent´. Or am I talking jibrish?

Comment: @Chamster - Unless the original set was ordered a certain way, no.

Comment: @Chamster In linq-to-objects, sure.  `Select` will always maintain ordering for any `IEnumerable`.  An `IQueryable` `Select` call is done in the database, so it depends entirely on that provider, and that database design, for whether or not the queries will always have the same ordering.

Comment: @Servy - Do you have a link to documentation that guarantees LINQ To Objects will maintain order? The current implementation may, but that's far from a guarantee that it will remain that way. Building code on an implied promise is a good way to ensure that it will break down the line.

Comment: @JustinNiessner It is defined behavior that select maintains order, not just an implementation detail.

Comment: @Servy - That's why I was asking for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:

[Preserving order with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

It does appear, at least from this answer, that Select calls are guaranteed to be the same order.

I'd still follow this with an OrderBy(...).  It seems like you can never be sure with LINQ calls, so if someone comes in and adds an additional LINQ call, they may not know that you were expecting them to be the same order.

Comment: I agree with the pragmatical application but dislike the (potential) redundancy). :) When delivering, I'll go with your suggestion, though.

Comment: Your link only applies to Linq-to-Objects, not Entity Framework queries.