# Order of items after using LINQ Select extension method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserving order with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

Supposing I have the following `Person` class that is further used to declare an array of `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var persons = new[] {
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John", Age = 40 },
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "John", Age = 30 },
    new Person { Id = 3, Name = "John", Age = 35 },
};
```

I extract the `Age` from the array of `Person`, using the following LINQ `Select` extension method,

```
var ages = persons.Select(p => p.Age).ToArray;
```

Does LINQ guarantee that the order of the items in the derived array matches the order of the items in the source array such that the `ages` array would be in the following order?

```
40
30
35
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The LINQ to Objects operators don't actually change their original data source -
>       they build sequences which are effectively backed by the data source. The only
>       operations which change the ordering are OrderBy/OrderByDescending/ThenBy/
>       ThenByDescending - and even then, those are stable for equally ordered elements.
>       Of course, many operations will filter out some elements, but the elements which
>       are returned will be in the same order.

From [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204512/128217).

A breakdown of each operation that returns IEnumerable is further down in that same question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/128217

Answer (score 6):

`Select()` preserve the order. It totally does.
Just be careful when you use `Distinct()`, `ToDictionary()` and `ToLookup()`.

Comment: Actually, I was using a `Distinct()` in the actual code. What should I be ware of?

Comment: It doesn't preserve the original order... well, you can't be sure that it will be preserved, that's different.

Comment: @Zarathos Distinct actually preserves the original order (at least in the current implementation) although this isn't a guarantee of the documentation.

Comment: Well, this is what I said Servy: "you can't be sure that it will be preserved".

Comment: I prefer the straight forward answer.

Answer (score 2):

This varies somewhat by which objects and extension methods you use.  Here's a post that makes the rundown of the types and what you can expect: [Preserving order with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

Items are processed in the order they are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Select for the most part takes an enumerable and applies an operation over each element in order.

You can think of it like this:

```
public static class Linq
{
    // We take in some data structure that supports enumeration and some function to apply to each element.
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TResult> operation)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            // Here we simply return the next element
            // when the caller wants an item.
            yield return operation(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the question is is guaranteed in specs, or are they allowed to change that behavior in a future implementation?  In this case, yes, and that's different than saying it's just a side effect of the current implementation.