# Using Where on a list previously sorted

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List<> that I've previously sorted by one of the fields on the object.  If I perform a Where() on the list, am I safe to assume that the results of the Where will also be sorted?

```
// Sorted by salary, greatest to smallest.
List<Players> players = _playerRepo.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).ToList();

// Is this list safe to assume that the players with smith as last name are sorted by salary as well?
List<Players> filteredPlayers = players.Where(x => x.LastName == "Smith").ToList();
```

Comment: Yes.  But you probably should have a get by last name method instead of pulling everything into memory and then filtering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserving order with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

Comment: The question is why you'are always creating lists. I would do the `ToList` only once at the end to safe memory and cpu cycles.

Comment: Guys, it's just a contrived example to explicitly ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Where` will not change the order of a previously ordered list, it will only filter it.

Also, the ordering operations are *stable*, so equal values will stay in their original order.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. LINQ queries, in general, keep the order of elements.

Hint: don't call `ToList` if you want to filter the result further. You should peform query on the database, not on the client, if possible.

Comment: If you use the ToList() it execute's the query immediately. If not used it executes later, at the point when u need the information from the query. (some additional information on the previous comment)