# linq using order by, where, and select vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a Linq query that I am passing to a list, and then to the view through the viewbag.  I am trying to keep that list in a specific order, so that when I iterate through it I have control over the order in which it's displayed.

Here is the query:

```
ViewBag.attributes = (From row In db.tblCategory_Attributes
                                 Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemType
                                 Order By row.Category_Attribute_Identifier
                                 Select CStr(row.Attribute_Name)
                                 Distinct).ToList()
```

I am successfully passing this list to the view and iterating through it, but no matter what the values are always displayed in alphabetical order.  `Category_Attribute_Identifier` is an integer that aligns with the order I would like these values to be displayed in.

I've played around with the order of my statements quite a bit and I'm not having any luck.

Can you tell me how to distinctly select the `Attribute_Name`'s that correlate with my specific `Item_Type_Identifier` and order my results by the `Category_Attribute_Identifier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Distinct` is creating its own ordering again (because it shuffles through the result to filter out duplicates). Just do the sorting after the `Distinct`:

```
(From row In db.tblCategory_Attributes
 Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemType
 Select row
 Distinct)
 .OrderBy(Function(row) row.Category_Attribute_Identifier)
 .Select(Function(row) CStr(row.Attribute_Name))
```

Comment: trying to implement this I encountered error: `category_attribute_Identifier` is not a member of string.  So I added `Category_Attribute_Identifer` to the select statement as an `and`.  Afterwards I get error:  CatAttID is not a member of Long.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Group By` instead of `Distinct`

```
ViewBag.attributes = (From row In db.tblCategory_Attributes _
                      Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemType _
                      Order By row.Category_Attribute_Identifier) _
                    .AsEnumerable() _
                    .GroupBy(Function(r) r.Attribute_Name) _
                    .Select(Function(g) g.Key) _
                    .ToList()
```

Or use the extension method syntax which gives you the freedom of applying the extension methods in any order:

```
ViewBag.attributes = db.tblCategory_Attributes _
    .Where(Function(row) row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemType) _
    .Select(Function(row) New With {row.Attribute_Name, row.Category_Attribute_Identifier}) _
    .Distinct() _
    .OrderBy(Function(a) a.Category_Attribute_Identifier) _
    .Select(Function(a) a.Attribute_Name) _
    .ToList()
```

---

This simple test demonstrates that `GroupBy` preserves the order:

```
Public Shared Sub TestGroupOrder()
    Dim a = New Integer() {6, 2, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 4}
    Dim query = a.GroupBy(Function(i) i).[Select](Function(g) g.Key)
    For Each i As Integer In query
        Console.Write("{0} ", i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Result in the console:

> 6 2 4 7 5 3

Comment: Grouping after ordering has the same effect.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq: "GroupBy - The IGrouping objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source. "

Comment: Yes, so that's `Attribute_Name`, but the required ordering is `Category_Attribute_Identifier`.

Comment: I don't think this means that the groups are reordered by the key, but that the order in which the keys are encountered first is kept.

Comment: The proof of the pudding... I know by experience that in LINQ-to-Entities the sort order of grouping key determines the ordering, but even then I never count on it. Often the ordering is even totally ignored in the generated SQL.

Comment: Remember that LINQ-to-Entities is not the same as LINQ in memory. It's really different. Just try.

Comment: Okay, I aggree on that. I added a `AsEnumerable()` in between, in order to separate the LINQ-to-EF from the LINTO-to-Objects part.