# Preserve order with linq after groupby and selectmany

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to preserve the order after this linq expression?

```
var results =
  DateList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Subtract(firstDay).Days / 7 + 1)
     .SelectMany(gx => gx, (gx, x) => new {Week =  gx.Key,DateTime =x,Count = gx.Count(),});
```

I found this [Preserving order with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204505/2657602) , but I'm not sure if its the GroupBy or SelectMany casing the issues

Comment: `GroupBy` retains order ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx)) and `SelectMany` only iterates over the set ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx)) so I don't see why it would change. Are you certain no order is preserved?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Think about what you are saying: Group the following sequence into odd and even numbers: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6] so now you have [1,1,3,3,5,5],[2,2,4,4,6,6] (yes, order was preserved *within each group*)... Now SelectMany on those groups and you'll get [1,1,3,3,5,5,2,2,4,4,6,6] (once again order was preserved)... But in combining the 2, clearly order has not been preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @spender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you first select your DateList and combine it with an index, using an [overload of `.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that uses a delegate with a second (`int`) parameter that is called with the index of the items from the sequence :

```
DateList
    .Select((dateTime, idx) => new {dateTime, idx})
    .GroupBy(x => x.dateTime.Date.Subtract(firstDay).Days / 7 + 1)
```

...and persist the value through the linq chain

```
    .SelectMany(gx => gx, (gx, x) => new {Week =  gx.Key,
                                          DateTime = x.dateTime, 
                                          Count = gx.Count(), 
                                          x.idx})
```

...then use it to re-order the output

```
    .OrderBy(x => x.idx)
```

...and strip it from your final selection

```
    .Select(x => new {x.Week, x.DateTime, x.Count});
```

then you can maintain the same order as the original list.

Comment: I got a blank result. What I do is run through this :

 var row2 = results.ElementAt(ii);
                        row["Week"] = row2.Week;
                        row["Count"] = row2.Count;  
                        row["DateTime2"] = row2.DateTime;


To add each value to a datagridview.

Comment: @Sewder I can't help you through a problem described so vaguely in a comment.

Comment: @loneshark99 Comments aren't a great place to ask new questions. Feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and ping me here if you'd like me to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of @spender is good, but can it be done without `OrderBy`? It can, because we can use the index for direct indexing into array, but it would not be one linq query:

```
var resultsTmp =
    DateList.Select((d, i) => new { d, i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.d.Date.Subtract(firstDay).Days / 7 + 1)
    .SelectMany(gx => gx, (gx, x) => new { Week = gx.Key, DateTime = x.d, Count = gx.Count(), x.i })
    .ToArray();

var resultsTmp2 = resultsTmp.ToArray();
foreach (var r in resultsTmp) { resultsTmp2[r.i] = r; };
var results = resultsTmp2.Select(r => new { r.Week, r.DateTime, r.Count });
```

It looks a bit complex. I would probably do something more straightforward like:

```
var DateList2 = DateList.Select(d => new { DateTime = d, Week = d.Subtract(firstDay).Days / 7 + 1 }).ToArray();
var weeks = DateList2.GroupBy(d => d.Week).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
var results = DateList2.Select(d2 => new { d2.Week, d2.DateTime, Count = weeks[d2.Week] });
```