# Why doesn't IOrderedEnumerable retain order after where filtering

Tags: c#, linq

I've created a simplification of the issue.  I have an ordered IEnumerable,  I'm wondering why applying a where filter could unorder the objects

**This does not compile while it should have the potential to**

```
IOrderedEnumerable<int> tmp = new List<int>().OrderBy(x => x);
//Error Cannot Implicitly conver IEnumerable<int> To IOrderedEnumerable<int>
tmp = tmp.Where(x => x > 1);
```

I understand that there would be no gaurenteed execution order if coming from an IQueryable such as using linq to some DB Provider.

However, when dealing with Linq To Object what senario could occur that would unorder your objects, or why wasn't this implemented?

**EDIT**

I understand how to properly order this that is not the question.  My Question is more of a design question.  A Where filter on linq to objects should enumerate the give enumerable and apply filtering.  So why is that we can only return an IEnumerable instead of an IOrderedEnumerable?

**EDIT**

To Clarify the senario in when this would be userful.  I'm building Queries based on conditions in my code, I want to reuse as much code as possible.  I have a function that is returning an OrderedEnumerable, however after applying the additional where I would have to reorder this even though it would be in its original ordered state

Comment: It shouldn't - that should be absolutely fine. If you're saying you're observing that not to be the case, please provide a [mcve]. In general, mind you, I'd advise filtering before ordering... why bother sorting a load of items you're about to ignore?

Comment: It might not be an `IOrderedEnumerable<int>`, but it will still be ordered, surely?  Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: Off topic perhaps, but why "where" after sort? Sorting will be faster on a smaller list.

Comment: The .Where() is just a function with a return type, just like any other, and that return type is IEnumerable, not IOrderedEnumerable. Anyway, you'll get better performance by filtering your data before you start to order it.

Comment: Does this line you provided even compile ?!

Comment: Once the query is ordered, there should not be a need to order it again when performing any operation that doesn't alter the order, like grouping or joining. The original order should be maintained. Agreed, should sort last, but this is still unexpected behavior. Otherwise we'd need to constantly sort to ensure that no other operation has changed the sort order.

Comment: Your `new List<int>()` will be empty for sure! What are you expecting to sort?

Comment: @JonSkeet that is a Verifable example that line does not compile

Comment: @user3185569 Its not suppose to compile that is the question why doesn't the filtering retain

Comment: I'd almost +1 for the "This does not compile while it should have the potential to", but no... it does not compile because it does NOT have the potential to compile...See answer by @Andrew

Comment: Can you provide a sample list that resulted in a wrong result ?

Comment: @JonSkeet that is a simiplified version of the issue, this originally was coming from a method that included the ordering and I was applying filtering afterwards normally I would do ordering last

Comment: @Leon It has the potential to compile because the where will not unorder the enumerable

Comment: @johnny5: The `Where` method won't change the order of the items, but it won't return an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`. It's important to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @johnny5 it does not : because it does not return an IOrdered.. so the compiler is right (as it always is)

Comment: To respond to your final edit - if you change your method to return `IEnumerable<T>` instead, what breaks?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rene's answer is correct, but could use some additional explanation.

`IOrderedEnumerable<T>` does not mean "this is a sequence that is ordered".  It means "this is a sequence that has had an ordering operation applied to it **and you may now follow that up with a `ThenBy`** to impose additional ordering requirements."

The result of `Where` does not allow you to follow it up with `ThenBy`, and therefore you may not use it in a context where an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` is required.

Make sense?

But of course, as others have said, you *almost* always want to do the filtering first and then the ordering. That way you are not spending time putting items into order that you are just going to throw away.

There are of course times when you do have to order and then filter; for example, the query "songs in the top ten that were sung by a woman" and the query "the top ten songs that were sung by a woman" are potentially very different!  The first one is sort the songs -> take the top ten ->  apply the filter. The second is apply the filter -> sort the songs -> take the top ten.

Comment: That Makes sense but why can't we return an IOrderedEnumerable from a Where, if the original Enumerable is Ordered in the first place, applying a where should still retain it's order

Comment: Because we want to be able to apply `Where` to an `IEnumerable<T>` and `Where` is statically typed.

Comment: @johnny5: It *does* retain the order, but it doesn't return another `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`. It returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which has the same order as the input. Why would you want to do `foo.OrderBy(...).Where(...).ThenBy(...)`? Because that's all it would buy you...

Comment: Yes but we could have override the where to do the same more generically for ordered enumerables as well

Comment: @johnny5: You are right that *logically* a Where on an ordered enumerable could be made to return an ordered enumerable. It's a possible feature, it's just not one that was ever implemented. I was not in all the LINQ design meetings, but I don't recall this ever coming up; it is possible that no one ever thought of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet  thats assuming your only using linqs built in extensions,  however your internal code may have functions or logic that is build upon Iordered Enumerables

Comment: @johnny5 How about `Select` (and probably other operators)? Are you saying they had to declare (and implement, test, document etc) overloads for many LINQ operators just to retain an interface which only purpose to exist is to allow `ThenBy`?

Comment: @EricLippert, That last comment was more of the answer I'm looking for I was just confused on why this functionality wasn't provided when Theorietically for IEnumerables it should be possible

Comment: @johnny5: If you need the functionality of `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` just apply it after `Where`. There is no plausible reason to apply it before.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I building Queries based on these conditions I wanted to reuse as much code as possible however apply a where filter after returning an Ordered Enumerable did not return me an Ordered Enumerable but It had the potential to do so,  Ofcourse I could reorder it again but that seems like an unneeded extra step

Comment: @johnny5: If you have logic that only works with `IOrderedEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable`, that can only be because it needs to use `ThenBy`/`ThenByDescending`... so again, why would you want to split the ordering into "do a bit, then filter, then do some more"? Basically it sounds like you may have a design issue in your code, and you're putting the blame on LINQ.

Comment: That is a very interesting case for order then filter. Thanks @EricLippert.

Comment: @johnny5: Again, you don't have to reorder it again. It is still ordered. Just because it is an `IEnumerbale<T>` does not mean that it is unordered. `Where` does not change the order of the items! And `ThenBy` does not make any sense for Ints.

Comment: @JonSkeet you do have a point,  in my case i was using paging and it could have been extracted, This question was more of a why not have the functionality if it could.  But there still senario's in which it would be useful.  For instance you need to do validation based off nested filtering, where you are comparing objects in an enumerable side by side, and after each layer of validation you need to filter based off of more conditions.  You would be required to call that order by after each where which would be a hassle

Comment: @JonSkeet  Granted you could still order on the enumerable in that situation know it should be still ordered, perhaps you would like that type safety just to be sure.  There are still a finite amount senarios in which a developer could be using an ordered enumerable not just limited to then by

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That is not the only senario where you need an ordered enumerable, that is just the only one defaultly provided by linq but you could have requires on an enumerable that must be ordered see my previous example above

Comment: @johnny5: The type safety wouldn't buy you anything useful here. It's ordered, but what by? Maybe by a random number generator - you'd still end up with an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, but it's pointless. If you think there are reasons to use `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` beyond `ThenBy`/`ThenByDescending`, why not actually give them? Basically, the interface itself only provides `CreateOrderedEnumerable`, which is effectively only useful for `ThenBy` scenarios. You've given *no* good reasons why you really need an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` after a `Where` call, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Consider: we have a large collection of work tickets with a priority, a location, and a user name.  I want "tickets in the top 100 by priority, that are located in London, sorted first by priority and then by name". The most efficient way to do that would be "order by priority, take 100, where location is London, then by name."  If you run the filter before the take, you're getting the wrong results. If you run the filter after the then-by, you're sorting more items than you need to sort. I don't think this feature request is so crazy.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Noting of course that "take" also preserves ordering, same as "where".

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree your right there is always a way to design around it but, you may not always have that privilege when working with third party library's.  Perhaps the scenarios I'm referring to are too specific. I'm just coming from the why not perspective

Comment: @johnny5: If a third-party library is broken, that's its fault - it's not a problem with LINQ, IMO.

Comment: @EricLippert: It would seem odd for the "sorted first by priority and then by name" not to be included in the "taking" part, personally. You're defining a total ordering (assuming all tickets are unique in priority+name, at least) but then saying only part of that ordering is relevant when deciding which tickets to take. I can't think of any cases where I've wanted that, myself. Of course, it would help if LINQ to Object's ordering were lazy, instead of actually sorting the whole sequence before yielding anything. But I think not having an `Where(this IOrderable<T>, ...)` overload was okay.

Comment: (To state it a different way - even if there are tiny niche situations where this is useful, I think it's very reasonable that it was designed the way it was.)

Comment: As one final comment - there are other aspects that I'd like to be preserved across transformations which I think would be more useful... the prime ones being "efficient countability" and "efficient indexing". `Select` could support both; `Take` could support the latter, `OrderBy` could support the former.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I thoroughly agree! This is a niche case and like I said, I have no memory of this ever even being raised as a possibility. My point is simply that the original poster is correct in noting that there is no *necessary* impediment to the feature. The feature is possible and sensible. It just did not pass the bar of being thought of, designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped.

Comment: @EricLippert thank you, you've stated my point way more elegantly than I ever could

Answer (score 4):

The signature of `Where()` is this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

So this method takes an `IEnumerable<int>` as first argument. The `IOrderedEnumerable<int>` returned from `OrderBy` implements `IEnumerable<int>` so this is no problem.

But as you can see, `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<int>` and not an `IOrderedEnumerable<int>`. And this cannot be casted into one another.

Anyway, the object in that sequence will still have the **same** order. So you could just do it like this

```
IEnumerable<int> tmp = new List<int>().OrderBy(x => x).Where(x => x > 1);
```

and get the sequence you expected.

But of course you should (for performance reasons) filter your objects *first* and sort them afterwards when there are fewer objects to sort:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<int> tmp = new List<int>().Where(x => x > 1).OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `tmp` variable's type is `IOrderedEnumerable`.

`Where()` is a function just like any other with a return type, and that return type is `IEnumerable`. `IEnumerable` and `IOrderedEnumerable` are not the same.

So when you do this:

```
tmp = tmp.Where(x => x > 1);
```

You are trying to assign the result of a `Where()` function call, which is an `IEnuemrable`, to the `tmp` variable, which is an `IOrderedEnumerable`. They are not directly compatible, there is no implicit cast, and so the compiler sends you an error.

The problem is you are being too specific with the `tmp` variable's type. You can make one simple change that will make this all work by being just be a little less specific with your `tmp` variable:

```
IEnumerable<int> tmp = new List<int>().OrderBy(x => x);
tmp = tmp.Where(x => x > 1);
```

Because `IOrderedEnumerable` inherits from `IEnumerable`, this code will all work. As long as you don't want to call `ThenBy()` later on, this should give you exactly the same results as you expect without any other loss of ability to use the `tmp` variable later.

If you **really** need an `IOrderedEnumerable`, you can always just call `.OrderBy(x => x)` again:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<int> tmp = new List<int>().OrderBy(x => x);
tmp = tmp.Where(x => x > 1).OrderBy(x => x);
```

And again, in **most** cases (not all, but most) you want to get your filtering out of the way before you start sorting. In other words, this is even better:

```
var tmp = new List<int>().Where(x => x > 1).OrderBy(x => x);
```

Comment: I understand the symantics of why this doesn't compile my question is why   is the where implemented this way when filtered on an ordered enumerable should still retain that order

Comment: Check the answer again. I added something to the bottom the may help you.

Comment: I have internal functions that work Build Queries based on conditions, and there requirements are that the enumerables are ordered prior to, then by is just linqs only built in implementation for that but a user can create any type of function +1 for the explanation though

Comment: @johnny5 added one more segement to the end that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

> why wasn't this implemented?

Most likely because the LINQ designers decided that the effort to implement, test, document etc. isn't worth enough compared to the potential use cases. In fact your are the first one I hear complaining about that.

But if it's so important to you, you can add that missing functionality yourself (similar to @Jon Skeet MoreLINQ extension library). For instance, something like this:

```
namespace MyLinq
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return new WhereOrderedEnumerable<T>(source, predicate);
        }

        class WhereOrderedEnumerable<T> : IOrderedEnumerable<T>
        {
            readonly IOrderedEnumerable<T> source;
            readonly Func<T, bool> predicate;
            public WhereOrderedEnumerable(IOrderedEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
            {
                if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
                if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
                this.source = source;
                this.predicate = predicate;
            }
            public IOrderedEnumerable<T> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending) =>
                new WhereOrderedEnumerable<T>(source.CreateOrderedEnumerable(keySelector, comparer, descending), predicate);
            public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Enumerable.Where(source, predicate).GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

And putting it into action:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyLinq;

var test = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(n => new { Foo = 1 + (n / 20), Bar = 1 + n })
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Foo)
    .Where(e => (e.Bar % 2) == 0)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Bar) // Note this compiles:)
    .ToList();
```