# Delete specific characters in string C#

Tags: c#, string, character

I have a string that has all the available partition letters for allocation.

I want to delete each character (or drive letter) that is already in use from this string.

I have tried doing this:

```
string allletters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
DriveInfo[] d = DriveInfo.GetDrives();


string notusedletters = string.Empty;

foreach (DriveInfo drive in AllDrives)
{
    string driveLetterOnly = (drive.Name).Replace(@":\", ""); // remove ":\" characters from the drive letter
    notusedletters = allletters.Replace(driveLetterOnly, ""); // remove driveLetterOnly from the allletters string.
}
```

But notusedletters string always returns the initial value of allletters (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ).

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a `Replace` on `allletters` a new string will be created. `Replace` does not modify exists string.
To make your code work you should re-assign `allletters` on each iteration:

```
allletters = allletters.Replace(....)
```

Or just use this single line linq query:

```
string allletters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string notusedletters = new string(
  allletters.Except(
    DriveInfo.GetDrives().Select(d => d.Name[0])
  ).ToArray());
```

---

From comments:

> It should be noted that Except does not guarantee that the order is preserved

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/4685428) answer and it says that `Except` preserves order. To make sure I've decompiled System.Core

Please see implementation of `Except` with my comments:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(
  this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
  IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
  // I removed a null checks
  return Enumerable.ExceptIterator<TSource>(first, second,
    (IEqualityComparer<TSource>) null);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptIterator<TSource>(
  IEnumerable<TSource> first,
  IEnumerable<TSource> second,
  IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
  Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
  foreach (TSource source in second)
    set.Add(source);
  foreach (TSource source in first)
  {
    if (set.Add(source))
      yield return source; // elements will be yielded in same order
                           // as they appear in first sequence
  }
}
```

But to be 100% sure that behavior will not change in future you can use `OrderBy` as @ckuri suggested in comment:

```
string notusedletters = new string(
    allletters.Except(
      DriveInfo.GetDrives().Select(d => d.Name[0])
    )
    .OrderBy(c => c) // explicit ordering
    .ToArray()
  );
```

Comment: It should be noted that Except does not guarantee that the order is preserved. There fore if the original order is required an OrderBy might be needed too.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `notusedletters` or just keep the same string while using the `replace`.

```
string allletters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
DriveInfo[] d = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach (DriveInfo drive in d)
{
    string driveLetterOnly = (drive.Name).Replace(@":\", ""); // remove ":\" characters from the drive letter
    allletters = allletters.Replace(driveLetterOnly, ""); // remove driveLetterOnly from the allletters string.
}
Console.WriteLine(allletters);
```