# Converting to JSON Array without loosing order

Tags: c#, json

I'm using the following code to merge all json objects using NewtonSoft.

```
 var result = input.SelectMany(d => d.Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
                    .Select((value, index) => new {index, value})
                    .ToDictionary(iv => iv.index, iv => iv.value);
```

However I want to change it to json array without loosing the order. Using "toArray" just adds each individual json object to json array. How do I add only the values to the json array?

the value of result is ,

`{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","3":"d","4":"e"}`

im trying to get the output to be `[a,b,c,d,e]` sequentially without loosing the order of the index as in the key.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] where the input is defined **in code** in the [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.ToDictionary()` already [looses order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/8528014).

Without knowing the types of the variables you are processing, it is a bit difficult to provide a comprehensive answer, but you probably just want to replace `.ToDictionary` by `.Select(iv => iv.value.something)`, followed by `.ToArray()`. This will only give you the values and preserve order.

Comment: yes, but I use `iv => iv.index, iv => iv.value` to preserve the order

Comment: I will add the json object that Im trying to convert as json array

Comment: I have added the value of result

Comment: im trying to get the output to be [a,b,c,d,e] sequentially without loosing the order of the index as in the key.

Comment: So you are using `.ToDictionary()` as a means of sorting your values? In this case, replace it by `.OrderBy()`, followed by the `.Select()` and `.ToArray()` from my answer.

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately it says Type argument method can not be inferred :( could you please jot it down?

Comment: Could you add your input to the question, as code? This will really help providing a working solution :)