# Can a LINQ filter alter the ordering of the original list?

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine I have a `IEnumerable<string>` ordered alphabetically. If I filter it like `myStrings.where(s=> s.StartsWith(filter));`, will the resulting enumerator still be in alphabetic order or not necessarily?

EG: is it there any guarantee that the original order will be maintained?

Edit 1: there is a answer from 2008 about this question. I read it yes, but because it's 12 years old, and a lot changed since then, specially regarding .Net Core and TPL, I would like a fresh, authoritative answer on the matter, to subside further developments. `.Where` changing the order of a IEnumerable is the kind of problem that is VERY hard to pinpoint and troubleshoot

Edit 2: by "IEnumerable" I don't only mean `List<T>`, I also mean `Dictionaries<T,T>`, `Array<T>[]` and the whole `Concurrent` versions of it such as `ConcurrentBag<T>`, `ConcurrentDictionary<T,T>` and others

Comment: It will be in the same order as the original list (that matches your criteria only).

Comment: @Jawad any documentation to back-up your answer?

Comment: You can read the implementation of the LINQ `Where` method and see that it does not modify order. (It should enumerate the items, yielding only the ones that match the predicate.) It's not impossible for some other method called `Where` to modify order, but it would have to go out of its way to do so, and you would be able to see it in the implementation.

Comment: @Neil I would also recommend you check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/1390548

Comment: @jawas I could write a conforming collection that returns a different order every time you enumerate it. If the question was about List <string> then you are correct but that is not the question.

Comment: What reason do you have to think that `Where` _could_ modify order? Enumerables are processed in order, and `Where` simply tests them against the predicate and yields the ones that match. Any random `Where` method could do crazy things, but any sane implementation will not be doing anything but enumerating in order and yielding in order.

Comment: @DaveCousineau it would make sense on concurrent collections to process the collection on a parallel fashion, on a divide and conquer manner. Perhaps you ever heard of Quicksort, which implementation is also based on divide and conquer

Comment: Divide and Conquer is for reducing algorithmic complexity; IE: for reducing the number of comparisons performed in a sort. A Where operation is already linear and as far as I know does not benefit from that sort of thing. LINQ Where does not use parallelization. Yes there could be the issue with a parallel filter that the results are returned in arbitrary order, but that doesn't apply to LINQ Where.

Comment: @DaveCousineau "as far as I know" is not what the question is about. As far as I know also, `Where` doesn't change the order, but I never counted on it. But now I need to work on some very performatic code where, reordering a already ordered collection is a must-not. This is why I'm seeking an authoritative answer, based on hard evidence and not "there could be the issue with ..."

Comment: Read the implementation then. Or implement your own `Where`. Or filter it with a loop. Concurrency can mess things up, but that's not present here unless you're doing something else, and aside from that what you're asking here is not as complicated as you're making it. Where simply enumerates in order and yields in order. It's a pretty trivial implementation that you can read or implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this brilliant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/4141606) that explains which LINQ operations alter the order of an `Iterable`.

But to answer your question, the only two operations that destroy the order of an `Iterable` are:

- ToDictionary
- ToLookup

Comment: yes, I read that answer, but if you noticed its from 2008!!! 12 years is a long time and something might have changed along the way, specially with Task library and the .Net Core initiative