# how to get first object when the name is the same and Id is different with linq query

Tags: linq

I want to get the first one if there are duplicates and discard everything if the name is the same.

**Model**

```
var data = [
{id:1, name:"Jay"},{id:2, name:"Jay"}
{id:3, name:"Jay"},{id:4, name:"Jay"} 
]
```

**wish to get**

```
var result =[
{id:1, name:"Jay"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them by `name` and pick a first item out of the group.

```
var result = data.GroupBy(g => g.Name).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the first element of an IGrouping appeared first in the original sequence?

Comment: Good catch @Harald, According to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/5519709 it should preserve order.

Comment: I got this error with the first keyword 

System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (s.Name), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: Site
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
)

Comment: Did you convert the JSon to object before using that linq?