# What's the most efficient way to get an ordered list of values from SortedList<DateTime, float> where the keys satisfy a constraint?

Tags: c#, filter, where-clause, sortedlist

By efficient I mean shortest time for computation.

I came up with:

```
List<float> valuesLaterThanDate = new List<float>();
foreach (var kvp in sortedList.Where( t => t.Key >= selectionDate))
{           
   valuesLaterThanDate.Add( kvp.Value );
}
```

is there a more efficient way?  Or more compact expression?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write it as a more compact expression:

```
var valuesLaterThanDate = sortedList.Where(t => t.Key >= selectionDate).Select(t => t.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, is the resulting list guaranteed to be ordered by the original Keys for each value?

Comment: Yes, to the best of my knowledge, LINQ preserves the original ordering. Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq

Comment: @Charlieface: It's more compact, but it doesn't return the values.

Answer (score 2):

**There are two performance efficiencies you can make:**

- Use `IndexOfKey` to perform a binary search of the starting key. This has `O(log(N))` efficency.
- You can pre-allocate the list to do a more efficient insert.

```cs
var startIndex = sortedList.IndexOfKey(selectionDate);
var valuesLaterThanDate = new List<float>(sortedList.Count - startIndex);
for (var i = startIndex; i < sortedList.Count; i++)
{
    valuesLaterThanDate.Add(sortedList[i].Value);
}
```

Note that `IndexOfKey` just returns `-1` if the key is not found, so if that can happen then you may need to [implement binary search yourself](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9e5773cf180eca3972cce44d56f055f0957f8eab/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs#L652). There have been [complaints about this issue](https://philosopherdeveloper.com/posts/whats-annoying-about-sorted-list-index-of-key.html) in the past regarding `SortedList<T>`.

Comment: I want to point out that your solution only works if the key `selectionDate` is present in the original list. Of course, you kind of mention it in your last sentence, but I think this is a major drawback of your solution.

Comment: Depends on your metric: more code (to implement `BinarySearch` if necessary) or more compact. I've added a link to the .NET implementation. `SortedList` is a particular bugbear, `List` does have a proper `BinarySearch`

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way? This is not answerable, as you have not laid out any the criteria to measure/determine efficiency. Performance efficiency? Memory usage efficiency? Code readability/maintainability?

A more compact form? Yes:

```
var valuesLaterThanDate = sortedList
    .Where(t => t.Key >= selectionDate)
    .Select(t => t.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `sortedList.Keys.Where...` is even more compact, if that's your metric