# Taking elements from an IOrderedEnumerable in LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core

This feels like an obvious requirement, but LINQ is fighting me.

I have collection of objects that I need to order.  So my interface returns an `IOrderedEnumerable`.

Requirements change, and now I only need to take the first 10 elements.  So I use `.Take()`, but now it returns `IEnumerable` (technically it is returning an `OrderedPartition`, but that doesn't implement `IOrderedEnumerable` so I can't even cast).  To conform to my existing interface, I now need to do the nasty (order, then take, then order again):

```cs
Dictionary<string, int> tagCounts = ...
IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> orderedTags = tagCounts
    .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .Take(10)
    .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Surely this is a problem that has been solved.  Is there a nice way to take the top *x* ordered items, and keep them ordered?

Answer (score 0):

Just return `IEnumerable` then from your method. Changing the returned interface does not change the behavior of the returned enumerable during the enumeration.

`Take` and `Skip` methods should preserve order. From [remarks in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-7.0):

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence.

> The `Take` and `Skip` methods are functional complements. Given a collection sequence `coll` and an integer `n`, concatenating the results of `coll.Take(n)` and `coll.Skip(n)` yields the same sequence as `coll`.

Comment: `IEnumerable` does not guarantee order.  Whilst it is likely the underlying implementation will maintain the order after `Take`, it seems like poor design for a public interface.

Comment: @Ian the same way you can say that `IEnumerable`/`IOrderedEnumerable` does nor guarantee that it will not add new elements, so the `Take` is not satisfied also. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204505/preserving-order-with-linq)

Comment: @Ian also non-preserving order implementation of `Take` does not make much sense and should fail to satisfy the quoted (see the update) guarantee.

Comment: Yes, I saw that post saying that `Take` will preserve order.  I couldn't find a more authoritative source.  And yes, I agree that if it does not preserve order, it will break the take/skip rules.  So the MSDN documentation _implies_ that it will preserve order. But it feels like a massive step backwards to revert `IOrderedEnumerable` to a simple `IEnumerable`. I'd rather do the nasty and call `OrderBy` again to maintain the return type.  I just thought there must be a nicer solution.
It would be niceif there was a `Take` extension that operates on *and* returns `IOrderedEnumerable`